# Evaluate $\int^{\pi/3}_0 \sin x \ln (\sec x)\text{dx}$

Tags: integration

$\int^{\pi/3} _0 \sin x \ln (\sec x)\text{dx}$

So far I have:

$u=\ln(\sec x), v'=\sin x$

$u'=\cos x, v=-\cos x$

$[-\cos x \ln (\sec x)-\int-\cos^2 x dx]^{\pi/3}_0$

Is this right so far?

Comment: The derivative of $\ln\sec x$ is $\tan x$

Comment: Rewrite $\ln(\sec x)=-\ln(\cos x)$, there's an obvious substitution you can use now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: better yet, try substituting $u=\cos{x}$. Then,

$$\begin{align}I&=\int^{\pi/3} _0 \sin x \ln (\sec x)\text{dx}\\
&=-\int^{\pi/3} _0 \sin x \ln (\cos x)\text{dx}\\
&=\int^{1/2} _1 \ln (u)\text{du}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I got $[u \ln u - u]^{1/2}_1


(\frac{1}{2} \ln\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2})-(\ln 1-1)


\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{3}{2}$, which is not the answer in the back: $\frac{1}{2}(1-ln2)$

Is my answer correct?

edit: my lines won't separate so it'll be hard to read, sorry...

Comment: @Jim It looks like you forgot to distribute negative sign. $-\frac12-(-1)\neq\frac32$.

Comment: Ah thanks, even so, I get $\frac{1}{2}(\ln \frac{1}{2}+1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jim Think about the basic algebraic rules for dealing with logarithms: $\log\frac12=\log 1 - \log 2$. See it now?

Comment: Ah, thank you! I always forget to use that log law...